# Update some values for a user in the database, depending on its access

Tags: c#, mysql

I am struggling with some C# database since a few days. I am trying to update a field depending on a user's access. I am trying to see that, if the player with the specified name has the required admin access, then he can use the command to update the level.

What I have tried

```
public void CMD_SetLevel(Player player, Player target, int level)
    {
        IPlayer pl = new IPlayer();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
                
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=@name LIMIT 1";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", player.Name);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Main.ServerLog("The server enters the setlevel reader");
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Main.ServerLog("The server enters the rows if");
                    reader.Read();
                    pl.AdminLevel = Convert.ToInt32(reader["adminlevel"]);
                    pl.Level = Convert.ToInt32(reader["level"]);
                    pl.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
                    Main.ServerLog("The server enters the row check from setlevel");
                    if (pl.AdminLevel < admLevels[9])
                    {
                        Main.ServerLog("The server enters the admin level check from setlevel");
                        player.SendChatMessage("[ERROR] You must be " + admRanks[9] + " !{#FFFFFF}to use this command");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Main.ServerLog("The server enters the admin level 2 check from setlevel");
                        command.Parameters.Clear();

                        if (target.Equals(player))
                        {
                            Main.ServerLog("The server enters the admin level 3 check from setlevel");
                            command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET level=@level WHERE name=@name";
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", level);
                                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", pl.Name);
                            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            player.SendChatMessage("You have set your level to " + pl.Level);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET level=@level WHERE name=@name";
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", pl.Level);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", pl.Name);

                            player.SendChatMessage($"You have set {target.Name}'s level to " + level);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

What I expected: if the player with admin access 10 (admLevel[9]) uses the /setlevel command, he can update the specified target's level. The chat messages work fine, but the value is not updated in the database..

This is the part of my constructor, related to this

```
    public class IPlayer : Script
    {
        private static string connString = "SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=worldstreetlife; UID=world; PASSWORD=password!";
        public static readonly String DataIdentifier = "PlayerData_Identifier";
        public Player Player { get; set; }
        public int ID;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public long Cash { get; set; }
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public int Armor { get; set; } 
        public int AdminLevel { get; set; }
        public int VIPLevel { get; set; }
        public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
        public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }

        List<int> AdminRanks = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<int> VIPRanks = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        List<string> admRanks = new List<string>() { "!{#FFCC99}Basic Helper", "!{#FFA64D}Helper", "!{#FF8000}Head Helper", "!{#FFFF66}Basic Moderator", "!{#AAFF80}Moderator", "!{#00FF00}Global Moderator", "!{#009900}Head Moderator", "!{#FF8566}Administrator", "!{#FF471A}Head Administrator", "!{#FF0000}Owner" };
        List<string> vipRanks = new List<string>() { "!{#C0C0C0}Silver VIP", "!{#FFD700}Gold VIP", "!{#006600}Advanced VIP", "!{#BFFF00}Premium VIP" };


        public IPlayer()
        {
        }


        public IPlayer(string name, int level, long cash, int adminlevel, int viplevel)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Level = level;
            this.Cash = cash;
            this.AdminLevel = adminlevel;
            this.VIPLevel = viplevel;
        }
```

Comment: It doesnt look like you execute either of the update queries.  Also it seems like picking the player by Id (since you have it) would be more certain than by name

Comment: Yes, the update queries do not execute and this is what I am struggling to find out why. I have just tried the ID and it does not enter the "if (reader.HasRows)" ... it only enters all the if blocks if I get the user by the name, where the name is the actual username account. Also the "Player" class is from a library I am using for this project, hence why "player.Name", as the Name field is from that class.